# Sql Exception Incorrect syntax near '@errno'

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm new to Vb.net and Linq2sql,and I searched on google for a solution before posting a question here but I couldn't Fix it ,I'm trying to Insert row into data base using Vb.net and Linq2sql, the SubmitChanges() function returns Incorrect syntax near '@errno' SQl Exception.
table related trigger:

```
 USE [Roster]
 GO
 /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[ti_profile]    Script Date: 11/14/2017 
 4:17:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ti_profile] on [dbo].[PROFILE] AFTER  INSERT
AS 

BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @ls_profile_code  varchar(6)
declare @errno int
declare @errmsg varchar(255)


--set @ls_profile_code = select inserted.profile_code from inserted

-- insert what ever was added to the object table and not yet been inserted or updated in the profile_access
insert into Profile_access (profile_code , object_code)

    select  (select inserted.profile_code from inserted) ,
            object_code
    from    Objects
    where   object_code not in

        (
            select  object_code
            from    Profile_access 
            where   profile_code = @ls_profile_code
        )




return

error:
raiserror @errno @errmsg
rollback transaction


END
```

Any Idea on how to fix this please..

Comment: First tag the correct database in use.. MySQL is not the same as SQL-server.

Comment: What is Profile and how is linked to the db? Do you have a trigger or function with @errno parameter?

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank you ,it was a mistake

Comment: There is nothing similar to `@errno` in your code, so we cant help. Look on your db for a trigger.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I updated my question please take look at it.

Comment: I think you should check `AFTER INSERT` [**example**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39970/sql-server-after-insert-trigger) Make it simple and keep adding things until you have what you need.

Comment: Your trigger has some serious issues. You have a named block in there but nothing ever uses a goto to get there. This is good because goto should not be used. The other issue is that your trigger will never actually do anything because @ls_profile_code is never set to a value so the insert statement will never find any rows.And don't use queries in your column like that either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `RAISEERROR()` function [requires parentheses now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669227/raiserror-issue-since-migration-to-sql-server-2012). This changed between Sql Server 2008 R2 and Sql Server 2012.

So this:

```sql
raiserror @errno @errmsg
```

becomes this:

```sql
raiserror(@errmsg, @errno, 1)
```