# What is not supported in SQL Server 2016 over 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I want to upgrade SQL Server from 2008 R2 to 2016. Is there a query on SQL Server 2008 R2 that is no longer supported on SQL Server 2016?

For example, I found that the `RAISERROR` function in the `RAISERROR 50001 'xxx'` format cannot be used anymore and must use the format `RAISERROR ('xxx', 16.1)`.

Comment: You're asking people to guess what your code looks like. In any case, you'll find the list of changes in the docs.

Comment: BTW that syntax [changed in *2005*, not 2016](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/raiserror-syntax-in-2008r2-vs-2012). You were already using a deprecated syntax that was eventually removed in *2012*. It looks like `RAISERROR 50001 'xxx'` was [undocumented to begin with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21669322/134204)

Comment: `RAISERROR` was introduced in SQL Server 7.0 (last century). Even then, the documented syntax always included the parentheses and commas. It's a little mystifying how people have kept hitting on the undocumented syntax and kept using it over the years. Presumably someone thought it was a neat hack because it allows you to use both an error number and a message, whereas the documented syntax allows only one or the other.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos;  @jeroenmostert
thank you for your answer,
where can I find documents that list the changes?..
I found several articles like
https://documentation.red-gate.com/codeanalysis/deprecated-syntax-rules

Comment: Have you tried *SQL Server's docs*? SQL Server *always* provided extensive documentation, first as offline help (called Books Online for a reason), then as online docs. Currently all of Microsoft's documentation can be found in https://learn.microsoft.com/

Comment: [Breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017) are clearly documented, along with links to older versions. You can find more information at the documentation for [compatibility levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level), which documents all the major and minor stuff that changes as you move to newer compat versions. Even among all those lists the `RAISERROR` breakage isn't documented, because the original syntax never was either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a good feel of your possible structure and code changes you should run the [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) first. This will detect code compatibility issues and suggest performance and reliability improvements for your target environment. But for your overall upgrade project I would recommend following the extensive walkthrough from https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/upgrading-sql-server-2016-part-one